# C++ pre-processor: unroll list of parameters

Tags: c++, list, macros, iteration, preprocessor

I want to define a macro with many parameters which expands to do the same thing for all the parameters. So

```
do_many(a, b, c)
```

(where a, b and c are class names) expands to

```
do_one(a);
do_one(b);
do_one(c);
```

which in turn expands into

```
void send(a &param) {
  //body
  }
void receive(a &param) {
  //body
  }
void process(a &param);
  // Body to be declared later

void send(b &param) {
  //body
  }
void receive(b &param) {
  //body
  }
void process(b &param);
  // Body to be declared later

void send(c &param) {
  //body
  }
void receive(c &param) {
  //body
  }
void process(c &param);
  // Body to be declared later
```

I.e. I am declaring a set of C++ overloaded functions for each of the parameters of the base do_many macro.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. And frankly, why you're doing this with macros as opposed to variadic template functions is the bigger mystery to me, but that's probably only because the source problem is also elusive.

Comment: a) what's the problem b) why templates cannot be used for this?

Comment: The problem is that I want to define functions to be called asynchronously at a later time. The function is "an_object.send(<a_struct>)". The hosts are Worker objects that communicate by sending messages. which are structs. So each Worker wants to say "sends(control, in_req, out_req" and "receives(connection_report, system_state_change). The macro then defines the functions needed.

Comment: Can a template have a variable number of parameters, of multiple types, and be a base class for further inheritance?